# Woocommerce - add to cart on content-product.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im trying to put add to cart on content-product.php but without success.

I need a button that when the person clicks add to cart automatically.

I tried to put this:

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

   <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

   <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>

   <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
</form>
```

The button looks ok but dont add to cart...

Someone can help me?

Im using Woocommerce 2.1.5

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
```

to the content-product.php file should add the "Add to cart" button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
When i add this action he send me this:
    <a class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_variable" data-product_sku="" data-product_id="146" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.multimidiaproducoes.com.br/woocommerce/loja/alimentacao/inflamacao/">Ver opções</a>

To see options, and send me to single product page, i want to add to cart directly...

Thanks so much to helping me

Comment: I think this occurs because is not a simple product, is a variation product..... :/
I cant have the variation and the add to cart button?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. You could add a test product that isn't a variation and check.

Comment: Yeap is this, if i put add to cart on content i need to put variations selection and quantity... if u know how i can do this ll be nice :)

Comment: I don't know I am sorry. You might need to start a new question and ask it there.